# Is it possible to call dll using ctypes from multiple threads?

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, dll, ctypes

I have a simple python script which loads a dll and calls exported function from two threads. Looks like script suddenly stops when second thread is started. Why is that? Is it unsupported to call dll functions from multiple threads?

**My script:**

```
import ctypes
import threading
import time

def tfunc():
    while True:
        my = ctypes.CDLL('/cygdrive/m/Workspace/py/src/cpp/ctypes-example.dll')
        my.test.restype = None
        my.test.argtypes = ()
        my.test()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=tfunc, daemon=True)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=tfunc, daemon=True)

t1.start()
time.sleep(1)
t2.start()

print('still here...')
```

**Output:**

```
$ python python-dll-thread.py
Load working...
Hello from dll: 0
Hello from dll: 1
...
Hello from dll: 1078
$
```

**ctypes-example.hpp:**

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>

extern "C" {

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved);
void test(void);

}
```

**ctypes-example.cpp:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "ctypes-example.hpp"

void test(void) {
    static int a = 0;
    printf("Hello from dll: %i\n", a);
    ++a;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {

    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            // Code to run when the DLL is loaded
        printf ("Load working...\n");
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // Code to run when the DLL is freed
        printf ("Unload working...\n");
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            // Code to run when a thread is created during the DLL's lifetime
        printf ("ThreadLoad working...\n");
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            // Code to run when a thread ends normally.
        printf ("ThreadUnload working...\n");
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Here is how I build this dll on cygwin:

```
$  g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -fPIC ctypes-example.cpp -o ctypes-example.o
$  gcc -shared ctypes-example.o -o ctypes-example.dll
```

Comment: This is not related to the DLL calls. A Python program terminates when all non-daemon threads terminated. You only have the main thread as non-daemon which terminates after the "print('still here...')"

Comment: `print('still here...')` is never executed. I can even add there endless loop and result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is having both threads being daemons, when the only non-daemon thread exits, the daemon threads terminate.

Since your are writing a `DllMain` you may want to read [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices) as well.  The code works for me on the Microsoft compiler, but other runtimes may create race conditions in DllMain (perhaps due to the printf?) if they trigger other DllMain calls.

This works in the Microsoft compiler:

test.c

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define API __declspec(dllexport)

API void test(void) {
    static int a = 0;
    printf("Hello from dll: %i\n", a);
    ++a;
}

API BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            // Code to run when the DLL is loaded
            printf ("Load working...\n");
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // Code to run when the DLL is freed
            printf ("Unload working...\n");
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            // Code to run when a thread is created during the DLL's lifetime
            printf ("ThreadLoad working...\n");
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            // Code to run when a thread ends normally.
            printf ("ThreadUnload working...\n");
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

test.py

```py
import ctypes
import threading
import time

my = ctypes.CDLL('./test')
my.test.restype = None
my.test.argtypes = ()

def tfunc():
    while True:
        my.test()
        time.sleep(.1) # slow down a bit

t1 = threading.Thread(target=tfunc, daemon=True)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=tfunc, daemon=True)

t1.start()
t2.start()

print('still here...')
time.sleep(1)  # illustrate threads stop after main thread exits
```

Output

```
Load working...
ThreadLoad working...
Hello from dll: 0
ThreadLoad working...
Hello from dll: 1
still here...
Hello from dll: 2
Hello from dll: 2
Hello from dll: 4
Hello from dll: 4
Hello from dll: 6
Hello from dll: 6
Hello from dll: 8
Hello from dll: 8
Hello from dll: 10
Hello from dll: 10
Hello from dll: 12
Hello from dll: 12
Hello from dll: 14
Hello from dll: 14
Hello from dll: 16
Hello from dll: 16
Hello from dll: 18
Hello from dll: 18
Unload working...
```

Comment: What compiler do you use to compile the library?

Comment: @Adam The Microsoft C++ compiler, but it shouldn't matter other than changing your undefined behavior.  Add the `return True` to DllMain and turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: Please note that `return True` is present in my original code. Just verified it on Visual Studio and I'm not experiencing the issue there (when `__declspec(dllexport)` added as you suggested). Looks like this issue is related to the cygwin environment which I have used to compile before.

Comment: @Adam Must have been a cut-n-paste error on my part I didn't it see in the original code until I scrolled it down.  Another possibility if you are hanging is a race condition in DllMain.  A loader lock is held during calls to that function, and if code in the function (printf?) causes another DllMain to be called it could deadlock.  Does it happen if you remove your custom DllMain or at least comment out printfs?  I edited the above to remove the `return True` problem.